# Simplified method for changing the color of a prefab

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the color of instanciated prefab. Till now I got this and it works pretty good:

```
 public class globalControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabInstance;
    List<Object> prefabInstanceClones = new List<Object>();
    GameObject capsule, sphere, cylinder;

    private void Start()
    {
        capsule = GameObject.Find("Capsule");
        sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");
        cylinder = GameObject.Find("Cylinder");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(prefabInstanceClones.Count);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
        {
            prefabInstanceClones.Add(Instantiate(prefabInstance, transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
        {
            capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("b"))
        {
            capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
            sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
            cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("g"))
        {
            capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
            sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
            cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }

}
```

The thing is my prefab consist of three objects - the in the code mentioned capsule, sphere and cylinder. Is there any way to combine all three together? I mean instead of writing it 3 times, that I just call somehow the main figure. Because I then have to do it for 4 more colors, and it's not a good style.

- I am creating clones using

  if (Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
              {
                  prefabInstanceClones.Add(Instantiate(prefabInstance, transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
              }

But when I click **r** for changing the color, only the color of the main figure is being changed and I need that all the clones also change their color. How can I do this?

Here is a smile for you :D

Comment: Hello, have you tried to use `GetComponentsInChildren` and use a `foreach` to apply this color? i.e.: [GetComponentsInChildren Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)

Comment: @vvilin I don't really have idea how this would work, please help

Comment: (1) `GameObject.Find` can only find active game objects already in the scene hierarchy. (2) you are not allowed to modify prefabs because they don't actually exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New created clone prefab should have the same color as the main one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227258/new-created-clone-prefab-should-have-the-same-color-as-the-main-one)

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting this solution, I could not try it right now but will edit it later if needed.

---

If you wish to "combine" your three prefabs, I would say you should have your three `GameObject`s under one empty `GameObject` in the scene:

- PrefabsParent

  - Cylindre
  - Sphere
  - Capsule

That way you only look for this parent, `PrefabsParent`, and have your `GameObject`s has its childs.

Then apply your color changes using the `GetComponentsInChildren`

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class globalControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Component[] renderers;
    void Start()
    {
        prefabsParent = GameObject.Find("PrefabsParent");
        renderers = prefabsParent.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    }

    /// Use this method when you wish to change the color 
    void ChangeColor(Color color)
    {
        foreach (var renderer in renderers)
            renderer.material.color = color;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        [...]
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
        {
            ChangeColor(Color.red);
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("b"))
        {
            ChangeColor(Color.blue);
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("g"))
        {
            ChangeColor(Color.green);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help, Good luck ;)

Comment: I must initialize prefabsParent  before calling it in the function Start(), but as GameObject it doesn't work, so I don't know how to initialize it :(

Comment: `foreach(var clone in prefabInstanceClones{
       capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
       sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
       cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
}`
Unfortunately my code doesn't work