# New created clone prefab should have the same color as the main one

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

First I'm creating a `prefab`. When I press r the color of the `prefab` is red. 
Now, I press the button c and the `prefab` is being cloned. The color of the clone is now white as default. But the first `prefab` has the color red so the clone should also have the same color. 
I tried to get the color of the `prefab` and then give it to the clone, unfortunately unsuccessfully.

My question is now, how can I give the clone of the prefab the same color as the main prefab? When I create three clones of prefabs and I press b for example, all four prefabs should be blue.

Look at my code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class globalControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabInstance;
    List<Object> prefabInstanceClones = new List<Object>();
    GameObject capsule, sphere, cylinder;

    private void Start()
    {
        capsule = GameObject.Find("Capsule");
        sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");
        cylinder = GameObject.Find("Cylinder");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(prefabInstanceClones.Count);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
        {
            prefabInstanceClones.Add(Instantiate(prefabInstance, transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
            var last = prefabInstanceClones[prefabInstanceClones.Count - 1];
            prefabInstanceClones.Remove(last);
            Destroy(last);
        }


        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
        {
            capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
            cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("b"))
        {
            capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
            sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
            cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("g"))
        {
            capsule.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
            sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
            cylinder.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance! Looking forward to hearing from you. :)

Comment: Your `r`, `g`, `b` keys are changing the colors of objects that are already in the scene, not the prefab.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate an instance of a prefab, i.e. create a clone of the prefab, the instance of that prefab can be modified and changed at playtime without updating the original prefab. However, the link to the original prefab is still maintained.

> Instance overrides allow you to create variations between Prefab 
>   instances, while still linking those instances to the same Prefab
>   Asset.
>
> When you modify a Prefab Asset, the changes are reflected in all of
>   its instances. However, you can also make modifications directly to an
>   individual instance. Doing this creates an instance override on that
>   particular instance.

This is core to Unity and allows you to make changes to your **instances** (instance overrides) at runtime.

For example:
We have a default prefab that represents an actor in your game, like an enemy droid, that changes color in different states - red when attacking, green when patrolling etc. We instantiate many copies and changes to each instance at runtime should be independent.

*When I press r the color of the prefab is red.
I press the button c and the prefab is being cloned. 
The color of the clone is now white as default. 
But the first prefab has the color red so the clone should also have the same color.*

So given the above, you can see that you are changing values of the instance of the prefab - an instance override at runtime. Any changes you make to your instances are not made on the original prefab. When you instantiate new prefabs, they will be independent instances of the **original** prefab.

**Secondly**

The call to find all the gameobjects is only run at `start()` - which only runs once at the start of the scene. `GameObject.Find()` will return a **single** gameobject matching the **name** provided that exists in the scene at the time. PS avoid using `GameObject.Find` for performance reasons - rather use [FindWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)

This means that your code to change the color is only changing those instances that exist at the start of the scene. There is no code to change the color of the clones.

To change the color of all the new clones, you can do the following:

```
        List<GameObject> prefabInstanceClones = new List<GameObject>();
        ...

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            prefabInstanceClones.ForEach(gameObject => { gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red; });
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer! But I am getting as an error `'Object' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponent' and no accessible extension method 'GetComponent' accepting the first argument of type 'Object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: Change the type in your list to be `GameObject`, not `Object`: `List<GameObject> prefabInstanceClones = new List<GameObject>();`

Answer (score 0):

```
  public GameObject prefabInstance;
List<Object> prefabInstanceClones = new List<Object>();
//GameObject capsule, sphere, cylinder;

private void Start() {
    //capsule = GameObject.Find("Capsule");
    //sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");
    //cylinder = GameObject.Find("Cylinder");
}
void Update() {
    Debug.Log(prefabInstanceClones.Count);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("c")) {
        prefabInstanceClones.Add(Instantiate(prefabInstance, transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("d")) {
        var last = prefabInstanceClones[prefabInstanceClones.Count - 1];
        prefabInstanceClones.Remove(last);
        Destroy(last);
    }


    if (Input.GetKeyDown("r")) {

        prefabInstance.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Color.red;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("b")) {

        prefabInstance.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Color.blue;

    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown("g")) {

        prefabInstance.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Color.green;

    }
}
```

You can use ().sharedMaterial this property effect all prefabs color.

Comment: (1) sharedMaterial means that all spawned copies will change color, which the asker probably doesn't want. (2) I am not sure you are allowed to access any components of uninstantiated prefabs.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately it didn't work. 
`MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "Figure" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Renderer to the game object "Figure". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
UnityEngine.Renderer.get_sharedMaterial () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/GraphicsRenderers.bindings.cs:140)
globalControl.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/globalControl.cs:37)`

Comment: Create a new material and attach the prefab object . it will work this way. @DerMitDemZeh